# Pyinstaller - Get exe file's name

Tags: pyinstaller

[ I used translator ]

I want to get the name of the exe file made from Pyinstaller.

I tried  `os.path.basename(__file__)` , but i returned python file's name(before using Pyinstaller).

I am sorry for my English and thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
os.path.basename(sys.executable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pyinstaller` to create .exe file, it will create the .exe file with the source code file name(ex- `demo.py` will produce `demo.exe` file at the output destination) if using `--onefile` and if you're using `--onedir` the .exe file will be stored with the same name as in `--onefile` but inside a folder with the same name, so the directory will be as follows: `output_destination/demo/demo.exe`

Comment: I think the question is looking for a way to detect the exe name at execution time (not build), in the same way `__file__` shows the Python script name. At least that's what I'm looking for having found this question.